# Django login problem which is being linked with the admin side

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am working on a Django project and have implemented login and  logout functionalities. The project is a job portal. When I login as a recruiter, previously I was able to open another tab in my browser and use the django admin panel. Now, whenever I do that, it says that I am logged in as my recruiter email address and I have to log in using another account. Now, when I log in using my admin credentials, simultaneously, I am being logged in on my website using my admin credentials which I have never registered on the site. Why am i getting this???

Thank you for your reply guys. This has impeded my work progress since hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its because django stores the login details in browser cookie ... so you have to use incognito  for using admin n other accounts

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to access the administrative page with your recruiting user as he must not have the flag `is_staff = True`, try add this flag to recruiting user and access the admin page of django.

Django does not allow the same user to be logged in to multiple accounts with the same browser window, so to access multiple accounts at the same time use anonymous tabs or other instances